# Delphi: Indy TIdTCPClient Reading Data

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

I am using Delphi 2007 & Indy 10; I am a bit of a Delphi noob so apologies if I have missed something obvious...

Background: I have a simple server app which simply sends the word "PING" when you connect to its port. It will also respond if it receives the word "PONG". This is working fine, I have manually tested this using netcat/wireshark.

I am trying to code my client to connect to the port and automatically respond to the word PING whenever it receives it. I have created a simple form with a button to manually connect.

The client connects, but it does not respond to the word PING. 
I think the problem lies with:

```
TLog.AddMsg(FConn.IOHandler.ReadLn);
```

My debug log reports only as far as "DEBUG: TReadingThread.Execute - FConn.Connected".

My client code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdCustomTransparentProxy, IdSocks, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdSync;

type

  TReadingThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    FConn: TIdTCPConnection;
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AConn: TIdTCPConnection); reintroduce;
  end;

  TLog = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    FMsg: String;
  procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const AMsg: String);
    class procedure AddMsg(const AMsg: String);
  end;


  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    IdIOHandlerStack1: TIdIOHandlerStack;
    client: TIdTCPClient;
    IdSocksInfo1: TIdSocksInfo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure clientConnected(Sender: TObject);
    procedure clientDisconnected(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  rt: TReadingThread = nil;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TReadingThread.Create(AConn: TIdTCPConnection);
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('DEBUG: TReadingThread.Create'); // Debug

  FConn := AConn;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('DEBUG: TReadingThread.Execute'); // Debug

  while not Terminated and FConn.Connected do
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('DEBUG: TReadingThread.Execute - FConn.Connected'); // Debug

    TLog.AddMsg(FConn.IOHandler.ReadLn);
  end;
end;

constructor TLog.Create(const AMsg: String);
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('DEBUG: TLog.Create'); // Debug

  FMsg := AMsg;
  inherited Create;
end;

procedure TLog.DoSynchronize;
var
  cmd : string;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('DEBUG: TLog.DoSynchronize'); // Debug

  cmd := copy(FMsg, 1, 1);

  if cmd='PING' then  begin
    Form1.client.Socket.WriteLn('PONG');
  end

end;

class procedure TLog.AddMsg(const AMsg: String);
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('DEBUG: TLog.AddMsg');  // Debug

  with Create(AMsg) do try
    Synchronize;
    finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Host : String;
  Port : Integer;
begin

  Host := '127.0.0.1';
  Port := StrToInt('1234');

  client.Host := Host;
  client.Port := Port;

  with client do
  begin
    try
      Connect;
      except
      on E: Exception do
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Error: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.clientConnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('DEBUG: TForm1.clientConnected'); // Debug

  rt := TReadingThread.Create(client);
end;

procedure TForm1.clientDisconnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('DEBUG: TForm1.clientDisconnected');  // Debug

  if rt <> nil then
    begin
      rt.Terminate;
      rt.WaitFor;
      FreeAndNil(rt);
    end;
end;

end.
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does the server respond with "PONG", or "PONG"#0D#0A ?

Comment: PONG, the server strips new line feeds, etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reading thread is directly accessing `Form1.Memo1`, which is not thread safe and can cause deadlocks, crashes, corrupted memory, etc.  So it is possible that the reading thread is not even reaching the `ReadLn()` call at all.  You **MUST** synchronize **ALL** access to UI controls to the main thread, no matter how trivial the access actually is.  Just don't risk it.

Also, you are doing your thread's ping/pong logic inside of `TLog` itself, where it does not belong.  Not to mention that you are truncating the `cmd` to only its first character before checking its value, so it will **NEVER** detect a `PING` command.  You need to move the logic back into the thread, where it really belongs, and remove the truncation.

Try this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdCustomTransparentProxy, IdSocks, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdSync;

type

  TReadingThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    FConn: TIdTCPConnection;
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure DoTerminate; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AConn: TIdTCPConnection); reintroduce;
  end;

  TLog = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    FMsg: String;
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const AMsg: String);
    class procedure AddMsg(const AMsg: String);
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    IdIOHandlerStack1: TIdIOHandlerStack;
    client: TIdTCPClient;
    IdSocksInfo1: TIdSocksInfo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure clientConnected(Sender: TObject);
    procedure clientDisconnected(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  rt: TReadingThread = nil;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TReadingThread.Create(AConn: TIdTCPConnection);
begin
  TLog.AddMsg('DEBUG: TReadingThread.Create');
  FConn := AConn;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
var
  cmd: string;
begin
  TLog.AddMsg('DEBUG: TReadingThread.Execute');

  while not Terminated do
  begin
    cmd := FConn.IOHandler.ReadLn;
    TLog.AddMsg('DEBUG: TReadingThread.Execute. Cmd: ' + cmd);
    if cmd = 'PING' then begin
      FConn.IOHandler.WriteLn('PONG');
    end
  end;
end;

procedure TReadingThread.DoTerminate;
begin
  TLog.AddMsg('DEBUG: TReadingThread.DoTerminate');
  inherited;
end;

constructor TLog.Create(const AMsg: String);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FMsg := AMsg;
end;

procedure TLog.DoSynchronize;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(FMsg);
end;

class procedure TLog.AddMsg(const AMsg: String);
begin
  with Create(AMsg) do
  try
    Synchronize;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Host : String;
  Port : Integer;
begin
  Host := '127.0.0.1';
  Port := StrToInt('1234');

  client.Host := Host;
  client.Port := Port;

  try
    client.Connect;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      TLog.AddMsg('Error: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.clientConnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TLog.AddMsg('DEBUG: TForm1.clientConnected');
  rt := TReadingThread.Create(client);
end;

procedure TForm1.clientDisconnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TLog.AddMsg('DEBUG: TForm1.clientDisconnected');
  if rt <> nil then
  begin
    rt.Terminate;
    rt.WaitFor;
    FreeAndNil(rt);
  end;
end;

end.
```

If that still does not work, then make sure the server is actually delimiting the `PING` string with a `CRLF` sequence, or at least a `LF` character (which is the minimum that `ReadLn()` looks for by default).

Comment: After 2 hours of breaking my head, if this help to someone, just remember: `make sure the server is actually delimiting the PING string with a CRLF sequence, or at least a LF character`